# Does this function satisfies the equation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, statistics, functions

I'm investigating on the following result.

Let $\phi(x)=G^{-1}(F(x))$, where $F$ and $G$ are the cdfs of two random variables.

I have to verify that

$$
\phi(x_2)-\phi(x_1)\geq x_2-x_1, \qquad \text{whenever} \quad x_1\leq x_2.
$$

My idea is the following (but it's not correct).

If $x_1 \leq x_2$, then $x_2-x_1 \geq 0$.

Since $F$ and $G$ are cdfs, they are non-decreasing.

So, if $x_1 \leq x_2$, $G^{-1}(F(x_1)) \leq G^{-1}(F(x_2))$. Then, it follows that $G^{-1}(F(x_2))-G^{-1}(F(x_1)) \geq 0.$

How can I connect the expressions $G^{-1}(F(x_2))-G^{-1}(F(x_1))$ and $x_2-x_1$ in order to prove the result?

Comment: If $F$ and $G$ are monotone nondecreasing, then also $G^{-1}$ is monotone nondecreasing. So the composition $G^{-1}(F(x))$ is monotone decreasing. Then does the thesis follow?

Comment: I don't think what you're claiming is true. Take $F$ as the cdf of an $\exp(1)$ random variable, $G$ as the cdf of a $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ random variable, $x_1=10$, and $x_2=11$.

Comment: Excuse me @met.91 I misread the question. This is not actually about monotonicity - you are asking for a stronger condition that $\phi$ is greater than linear in its argument. In this case, Matthew's comment and the fact that this is a strong condition suggests the result does not hold

Comment: @MatthewH. This result is written on a book published by Springer, but there's not a proof of that. They say it's true.

Comment: I don't really see how this can be true in general. Suppose $X\sim f=F'$ is a continuous random variable with a skewed right distribution and $Y\sim g=G'$ is a continuous random variable with a skewed left distribution. Also assume $X,Y$ is supported on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (which will provide us with a $G^{-1}$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Since the distribution of $X$ is skewed right $F(x_1),F(x_2)\approx 1$ can be very close together if $x_1,x_2$ are very large and far apart. Now because $Y$ is skewed left, the realizations of $G^{-1}(F(x_1)),G^{-1}(F(x_2))$ of $Y$ will have to be very close to each other, which makes your inequality false. Are there other conditions mentioned in the book that you've left out?

Comment: @MatthewH. The book gives this result as a good one and uses it to prove other thing about statistics and stochastic orders. It says that $\phi(x)$ satisfies the disequation $\phi(x_2)-\phi(x_1) \geq x_2-x_1$, whenever $x_1 \leq x_2$. I don't know how to go on in my work because I can't prove this result. Ugh!

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say $G^{-1}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. $G^{-1}$ is defined on $(0,1)$ and it's range is $\mathbb{R}$ (so it's "nice"). I could be mistaken, but I don't think this is necessarily true.